# angular2 output object value in html without specifying object name

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular

I'm trying to output JSON values in HTML using `ngFor` without specifying the object name to render the value in HTML, is this even possible?

I know that I have to specify the object name to actually render the value like the example below.

Let's say I have this JSON object:

```
'customerObjs':'Ob1'
'FirstName': 'Name'
'Something': 'Something'
```

And in HTML, I have to do something like the code below to show the value,

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of Objects">
   {{ obj.FirstName }}
</div>
```

However, the idea is to render the value even if you don't know the object name. Because what if the backend guy added a new object of `YouDontKnowWhatThisIs` then the HTML should still render the value of that `YouDontKnowWhatThisIs`.

So it's more of dynamically outputting the response with hard coding the object name.

Is this possible? If so can someone show an example?

Comment: Can you provide a plunker to this? You need to provide more info to get some good help. Look at your `customerObjs`, actually it is a list and not an object. It wont even work because it is an invalid JSON. But, try to use the json pipe like: {{obj | json}} so you will see all object fields.

Comment: edited my customerObj, use a pipe?

Comment: each time i diplsy json online is with `<pre>{{ Objects | json:true }}</pre>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom pipe that extract the keys and value from an object, so you can use them as you need.

keys.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

myview.html

```
<p *ngFor="let object of objects | keys">
  <b>{{object.key}}</b>
  <span>{{object.value}}</span>
</p>
```

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

If this behavior is only local to one component, you can define a getter in it that lists the properties in your object:

```
@Component({/*...*/})
export class {
    private obj;

    get props() {
        return obj ? Object.keys(this.obj.prop): []
    }
}
```

With the following template:

```
<div *ngFor="let prop in props">
   {{obj[prop]}} 
</div>
```

Comment: This is how I'm doing it now before I read this answer. Will give it an upvote :).

Answer (score 0):

If you're just debugging an object, you could do a lot worse than a cheeky JSON.stringify equivalent:

```
<pre>{{object | json}}</pre>
```